# Theme toggle caption Image may contain a

Tags: themes

Hhhhh

import {useState, createContext, useContext, useEffect} from "react"

const ThemeContext = createContext()

export const useTheme = () => useContext(ThemeContext);

export const ThemeProvider = ({children}) => {
const [theme, setTheme] = useState();

```
const toggleTheme = () => {
    const newTheme = theme === "dark-theme" ? "light-theme" : "dark-theme"
    setTheme(newTheme)
    localStorage.setItem("theme", newTheme)
}

useEffect(() => {
    const storeTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "dark-theme"
    setTheme(storeTheme)
},[])

return(
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{theme, toggleTheme}}>
        {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
)
```

}

import {useState, createContext, useContext, useEffect} from "react"

const ThemeContext = createContext()

export const useTheme = () => useContext(ThemeContext);

export const ThemeProvider = ({children}) => {
const [theme, setTheme] = useState();

```
const toggleTheme = () => {
    const newTheme = theme === "dark-theme" ? "light-theme" : "dark-theme"
    setTheme(newTheme)
    localStorage.setItem("theme", newTheme)
}

useEffect(() => {
    const storeTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "dark-theme"
    setTheme(storeTheme)
},[])

return(
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{theme, toggleTheme}}>
        {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
)
```

}

import "./ThemeToggleButton.css"
import { useTheme } from "../Context/ThemeContext";

const ThemeToggleButtom = () => {
const {toggleTheme} = useTheme();

```
return <button className="ThemeButton" onClick={toggleTheme}>Toggle button</button>
```

}

export default ThemeToggleButtom;

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code. Please add some more details so we can understand how we can help you.